# Does the cloud code plugin for intellij work with Azure

Tags: azure, intellij-idea, plugins, cloud

I see that GCP is set on default to sign in so wondering if it works with Azure and if so how do i connect to it

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Code IntelliJ Kubernetes features do work with any Kubernetes cluster, regardless of vendor, local or remote. Cloud Code uses standard kubectl configuration (kubeconfig file) to communicate with clusters. When you have your Azure cluster set up, make sure you have it configured on your machine for kubectl (so `kubectl config get-contexts` contains an entry for your Azure cluster and it is properly configured and accessible - please follow Azure Kubernetes configuration documentation for that).

Once Azure cluster is configured on your machine, it will appear in Cloud Code - you can use the Kubernetes Explorer, develop and debug on it just like with GKE or any other Kubernetes cluster of you choosing.